# DataTable importing issue with Excel custom format

Tags: c#, datatable

Need help on datatable issue, which I need original amount to datatable as shown in pic below but while i do import to datatable from excel where amount column showing as Date Time format.

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Post code please... we cant help you with this information

Comment: Excel is a Front end application that uses either the Jet or ACE driver as the backend for the database.  The Jet or ACE when column type is not specified (General Format) guesses as the column type and often makes mistakes.  You have to specify the column type to prevent errors.  Also you have to make sure the column index is correct.  Excel column indexes start at one while in Net they start at zero.  So you may be off by one index.